# How can I give full permission to folder and subfolder

Tags: permissions, directory

I'm new to Ubuntu and need to create a new folder in `/var` and need all users on the machine to have full permissions to this folder.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)**  Do you want to create a folder in `/var` that has full permission for all users???  **There is already one!**  and it's called `tmp`!

Comment: Thanks for replying , yes that i want to do but please what do you mean by There is already one! and it's called tmp!

Comment: /tmp is a system directory with a temporary filesystem which uses RAM memory. Anything put there will be deleted upon reboot.

Comment: @EduardoCola: it actually uses disk, but yes, it's deleted upon reboot! (You can see this happening when you remove `quiet splash` from the boot parameters...)  **;-)**

Comment: Isn't /tmp used with tmpfs? Which uses RAM?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to go to a terminal and type:

```
sudo mkdir /var/szDirectoryName
sudo chmod a+rwx /var/szDirectoryName
```

Where `szDirectoryName` is the name of the directory you would like, `a` means "all" (users) `+` means "add the following rights" and `rwx` means `r`ead, `w`rite and e`x`ecute respectively...

**Note:** *there already is such a directory* in `/var` which all users have access to: `tmp` (full path: `/var/tmp`) which itself is symlinked to `/tmp`.
Beware however that all files in `/tmp` are deleted at boot time.

*For any further information, **[here](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.pdf)** is a great resource on all directories in Linux.*

Comment: but what is that mean  after i executed your command i got total 0 when i wrote ls -l /var/nameoffolder?

Comment: i know that command ls .. used for listing what is in that folder but -l give me the permissions rigth ?

Comment: sorry , you edited your answer with statement i want to ask about there is already a directory in /var that all users have access to: tmp which is symlinked to /tmp this means that folders that i will created in /var will be deleted liken in /tmp

Comment: After this i am still getting error `-bash: cd: folder: Permission denied`  , when trying cd folder

Comment: @YourHelper Please ask a [new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) and provide more details there as to what goes wrong where *exactly*...  It might help to include a link to this question for reference.

Answer (score 89):

Open Terminal

Create Directory with `mkdir`:

```
sudo mkdir /var/DirectoryName
```

To give all permissions to a folder give `chmod -R 777`:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/DirectoryName
```

Comment: This works for me, since I also need to give all the sub folders the permissions.

Comment: Do we need to type full path here?

Comment: yes. we need to move to the path or we need to type the full path for the folder

Answer (score 7):

Below gives all permissions to everybody to all files and subdirectories:

```
chmod -R a+rwx path
```

Comment: Is this true for any new files/directories made or only for existing files and directories?

Answer (score 4):

To give all permissions to all the users, use the following command:

```
chmod -R a+rwx /path/....
```

**Note:** It's Usually not recommended to give every user every permission of a directory, be careful while using this command.

To give permissions to a specific user:

```
sudo chown -R username:grouname /folder_path
```