# How to get write permission for folder and subfolders

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo

In my Visual Studio code on ubuntu 19.04 I have created a folder with some content with a CLI tool called expo. However, my sudo user jonas does not seem to have rights to write to this folder since I have to verify password every save. Which is extremely daunting.

I have already tried the answer of

> [How can I give full permission to folder and subfolder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/719996/how-can-i-give-full-permission-to-folder-and-subfolder)

```
sudo mkdir /var/szDirectoryName
sudo chmod a+rwx /var/szDirectoryName
```

This is the output in the terminal

```
jonas@jonas:~/Projects/javascript-questions-flow3$ sudo chmod a+rwx /home/jonas/Projects/javascript-questions-flow3/react-native-flow-3
jonas@jonas:~/Projects/javascript-questions-flow3$ ls -l
total 140
drwxr-xr-x   4 jonas jonas   4096 jun 10 11:36 backend
drwxrwxr-x 246 jonas jonas  12288 jun 10 23:19 node_modules
-rw-rw-r--   1 jonas jonas   1216 jun 10 23:19 package.json
-rw-r--r--   1 jonas jonas 103310 jun 10 23:19 package-lock.json
drwxrwxrwx   6 jonas root    4096 jun 11 01:07 react-native-flow-3
-rw-rw-r--   1 jonas jonas   9586 jun 10 16:40 README.md
jonas@jonas:~/Projects/javascript-questions-flow3$
```

I expected the `root`in `react-native-flow-3` to change to my user as the rest. How can I give jonas sudo write access to this folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the rights of the files you want to access in react-native-flow-3

```
ls -l /Projects/javascript-questions-flow3/react-native-flow-3
```

who owns the files?

May be you need to add jonas to the group root too.

```
usermod -a -G root jonas
```

And why dont you change react-native-flow-3 from root to jonas?

```
chown jonas.jonas react-native-flow-3
```

May be you should got through this tutorial
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-linux-permissions