# cannot run nautilus-desktop

Tags: gnome, nautilus, 22.04, desktop-icons

Switched to ubuntu from windows a few days ago, I could open desktop folders as usual. But since tomorrow, when I double click a folder nothing happens, it doesn't opens. I can still open it through nautilus.

I found some similar problems on other posts and solution was that running `nautilus-desktop` could fix it.

https://askubuntu.com/a/1329590/1669217

But that command isn't there.

I get following errors:

```
gyan@gyan-Inspiron-15-3515:~$ nautilus-desktop
nautilus-desktop: command not found
```

I tried installing it but got another error:

```
gyan@gyan-Inspiron-15-3515:~$ sudo apt install nautilus-desktop
[sudo] password for gyan: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nautilus-desktop
```

running:

```
gyan@gyan-Inspiron-15-3515:~$ nautilus
```

opens the file manager as expected but I can't open folders from desktop.

Please help!.

Comment: There is no `nautilus-desktop` package in modern Ubuntu distros. It is unclear what you did to the system.

Comment: Maybe you've accidentally changed permissions for the Desktop directory, check permissions using 'ls -l' or update it using [chmod](https://askubuntu.com/questions/719996/how-can-i-give-full-permission-to-folder-and-subfolder).

Comment: Here is the output from `ls -l`          ```drwxrwxr-x 2 gyan gyan 4096 Jan 31 18:36 testfolder
```

Comment: Also I can open it as usual from file manager so I don't think permissions are a issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I fixed it. I decided to take a look at `/var/log/syslog` and found that gnome is trying to use wsl to open it, so I removed the `wslu` package by

```
sudo apt purge wslu
```

This fixed the issue for me, hope it helps any future visitors.